# How to Create Dynamic sub-Domains?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, subdomain

How to Create Dynamic sub-Domains and URL-routing in asp.net MVC3. How to Redirect to user`s page? eg. user1.domain.com, user2.domain.com etc. User name getting from database.

Comment: This questions has been answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159050/creating-sub-domains-on-signup

Comment: @KhumeshKumawat Hi! Would be nice if you will share how you solved that issue, please. Thank you in advance!